# How can you send idevicediagnostics restart -u command in appium to restart an ios device?

Tags: appium, ios

How can you send idevicediagnostics restart -u command in appium to restart an ios device?
I can send this via the terminal manually, but I would like appium to trigger it during the end of each test suite run. My goal is to reboot my ios devices after each test suite run without having to do it manually everytime. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("idevicediagnostics restart -u "+udid).waitFor();
             Thread.sleep(60000);